# How to hide the credit card charging amount after choosing COD in onePage checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, ce-1.9.2.4, magento1.9.2.4

I've enabled the COD options in a magento ce 1.9.2.4 store. In the onePage checkout if the user choose the COD option it's still visible in the `Order Review`
 a table row telling `Your credit card will be charged for` and giving the final value in the base currency. For me I want to hide this row ONLY if the user chosen the COD.

is there's a direct option for that? code hints? and to tell I've thought about a simple jquery solution but IDK is it okay to do so or there's a magento recommended solution?
This image taken from fresh installation:
[image: screenshot from fresh installation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite **Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Totals::needDisplayBaseGrandtotal()** function to achieve this with below code.

```
public function needDisplayBaseGrandtotal()
{
    $quote  = $this->getQuote();
    $hideForPayment = 'cashondelivery'; // Your Payment method code for which you want to hide message
    if ($quote->getBaseCurrencyCode() != $quote->getQuoteCurrencyCode() && $quote->getPayment()->getMethod() != $hideForPayment) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks so much. it worked perfectly. but should I edit `\app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Block\Cart\Totals.php` or overwrite the function elsewhere?

Comment: You MUST NOT edit any core Magento file. Better way to do this will be to put the file in your `local` folder. `\app\code\local\Mage\Checkout\Block\Cart\Totals.php`

Answer (score 0):

Did your order review reload after you change the payment method ?

Or you can check if there is JavaScript conflict/error from your browser

**Updated :**

Check this file, if you want to hide the code is up to you.

```
app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage\review\totals.phtml
```

or you can try this one :

[Hide display base grand total](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/2914/edit-your-credit-card-will-be-charged-for-on-onepage-checkout-to-show-desired)

Comment: it's in fresh installation too. so it's a magento core thing and not related to any extra as I think