# MAGENTO 2 - Remove "Your credit card will be charged for"

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout, onepage-checkout

Running Magento 2.1.7 - Running two (2) stores. One in Guatemala currency and another with Belize currency - Both have to use a USD Base Currency to process Credit Card and PayPal payments but I don't want the USD total to appear on the checkout page so that we don't confuse the clients.

I'm trying to remove ***or*** hide the **YOUR CREDIT CARD WILL BE CHARGED FOR...** field on the checkout page.

[image]

Need some help. Anyone out there with the answer? :)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/2914/edit-your-credit-card-will-be-charged-for-on-onepage-checkout-to-show-desired

Comment: The solution in the last post didn't work for me :(

Comment: The link Manoj provided was how to accomplish this in Magento 1.x and won't work in Magento 2.x

Answer (score 6):

There are a few different methods to accomplish this:

**Method 1.** Use a mixin to override the `isBaseGrandTotalDisplayNeeded` method in `Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/summary/grand-total`

> Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
  'config': {
    'mixins': {
      'Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/summary/grand-total': {
        'Vendor_Module/js/grand-total-mixin': true
      }
    }
  }
};
```

> Vendor/Module/view/frontend/js/grand-total-mixin.js

```
define(function () {
  'use strict';

  var mixin = {
    isBaseGrandTotalDisplayNeeded: function () {
      // you custom logic for displaying base grand total
      // returning false prevents the section from being displayed
      return false;
    }
  };

  return function (target) {
    return target.extend(mixin);
  };
});
```

**Method 2.** Override `Magento_Tax/template/checkout/summary/grand-total.html` using a module or theme and remove the section of the template you don't want.

Using a module:

> Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
  map: {
    '*': {
      'Magento_Tax/template/checkout/summary/grand-total.html':
        'Vendor_Module/template/checkout/summary/grand-total.html'
  }
};
```

> Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/summary/grand-total.html

Below is the template with the base grand total display removed.

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<!-- ko if: isTaxDisplayedInGrandTotal && isDisplayed() -->
<tr class="grand totals incl">
    <th class="mark" scope="row">
        <strong data-bind="i18n: inclTaxLabel"></strong>
    </th>
    <td data-bind="attr: {'data-th': inclTaxLabel}" class="amount">
        <strong><span class="price" data-bind="text: getValue()"></span></strong>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="grand totals excl">
    <th class="mark" scope="row">
        <strong data-bind="i18n: exclTaxLabel"></strong>
    </th>
    <td data-bind="attr: {'data-th': exclTaxLabel}" class="amount">
        <strong><span class="price" data-bind="text: getGrandTotalExclTax()"></span></strong>
    </td>
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: !isTaxDisplayedInGrandTotal && isDisplayed() -->
<tr class="grand totals">
    <th class="mark" scope="row">
        <strong data-bind="i18n: title"></strong>
    </th>
    <td data-bind="attr: {'data-th': title}" class="amount">
        <strong><span class="price" data-bind="text: getValue()"></span></strong>
    </td>
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```

The same template above can be placed directly in a custom theme without the module or requirejs-config by placing in `app/design/Vendor/Package/Magento_Tax/web/template/checkout/summary/grand-total.html`